# programmatically push to a new viewController after pressing uiAlert button

Tags: ios, uialertview, uialertviewcontroller

I was wondering if it is possible to push to a newViewController after pressing a button in the UiAlertController

my code looks like

```
 @objc func handleAcceptRequest() {
    let user = self.user
    let username = user?.name

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you Sure? ",message:" Would you like to accept \(username!) to complete your job?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

    let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
           print("you pressed cancel button")
       })

    let continueButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

        let vc = viewController()
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

           print("you pressed Continue")

       })



    continueButton.setValue(GREEN_Theme, forKey: "titleTextColor")
    cancelButton.setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "titleTextColor")
    alert.addAction(cancelButton)
    alert.addAction(continueButton)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

  }
```

I would only like to present the VC if the the Continue button is pressed but If I call the present

// self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

inside of the continueButton, I get the error Use of unresolved identifier 'present'

is it possible to push a newVC this way?

Comment: Your question doesn't provide much context where you're instantiating your `UIAlertController`. It looks like you are doing the instantiation outside of a `UIViewController` environment. Otherwise you'd get the `present(_:animated:completion)` method available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not right

```
// self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It should be:

```
self.window?.rootViewController?. present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Cheers, happy coding

Comment: Can you explain why ___this is not right___ as you wrote in the beginning?

Comment: I guess that you call this method in your `AppDelegate`. And the `present` method is not available for `AppDelegate`, it's available for UIViewController, that why you need to use self.window.rootViewController (an instance of UIViewController) to present the alert @nayem

Comment: Well, I see. In that case (as you're guessing) you should have been explaining this right in your answer as well.

Comment: @nayem Sure, thanks for your suggestion!, will do next times.

Comment: @nayem this is actually created inside of a UIView not in app delegate. Thanks for all of the help!

Comment: @Jacob thanks for your code, but I noticed that If I use this method, it removes the navigation bar at the top of the screen. is there a work around for this?

Comment: Please check you ViewController (which is embedded in UINavigationController) and make sure that navigation bar is not hidden from this controller @ZachWilcox